# Find which column has the minimum value of a sum of all rows, and having the the name of the column has output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sum of all rows of columns y1 to y7 of a data frame

```
y1     4.475017e+02
y2     4.825798e+02
y3     4.077346e+04
y4     1.083712e+04
y5     4.005989e+04
y6     4.223634e+02
y7     3.385693e+01
```

I need to find which column has min value, in this case it is y7, so I want the output to be just:
`y7`

**What I did:**

minimum = sum.min()

**output:** `33.85692709115603`

ideal = sum.loc[sum == minimum]

**output:**

```
y7    33.856927
dtype: float64
```

I had to print and manually insert `df["y7"]` later.

I want to be able to do this without printing, that is, inserting `df["y7"]` but without having to actually write `y7` since this will be the output of the prior input.

**Edit:**

Now that I have the output I wanted: `min = y7`, how do I mention a column with same name as the output?

Example: I need the output of the input `df["y7"]`, but instead of writing `y7`, I want to write the output of `min`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.sum().idxmin()
```

Example:

```
print(df)

    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15

df.sum().idxmin()

'A'
```

##### referencing the column:

```
col = df.sum().idxmin()

df[col]   # or without variable df[df.sum().idxmin()]

0     0
1     4
2     8
3    12
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! That gave me the output I needed. But now I have another problem, would like your help with it if possible. It is in the "Edit" part of my question

Comment: I was actually referencing the column correctly but it wasn't working. Turns out the variable was inside a nested function and I spent a couple hours discovering how to get it outside the function. It ended up being way easier than I expected. Anyway, thanks for your help. The program I've been doing for college for a couple weeks is now complete, free of errors or warnings.